# SCRIPT1002: Syntax error in CSS when bundling

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bundling-and-minification

I am trying to bundle my css like below.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(                     
                      "~/Content/styles.css"));
```

But when i run the code i get this.

```
JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 1 in
http://localhost:49934/Content/css?v=8I6_j_wgn_9yNhfGU_-N-R8Ya98JN2nc600cBlm8VBM1

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
```

Assuming my css had some funny characters or invalid paths, i removed everything except the below. It still did not work

```
.full {
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    padding-top: 52px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 55px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

When i disable bundling, add the link the usual way like below, it works

```
<link href="~/Content/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I googled and most of the links talk about javascript error in javascript. I dont know why i am getting Javascript error in css.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: there's no way JS would throw an error like that, unless somehow the css got stuffed into a `<script>` block. Did you look at the source of the generated page to see how the `bundles.Add()` worked out?

Comment: I cant believe i have wasted almost 2 hours for this. Thanks for your suggestion. I am embarrassed to say what i did wrong. Instead of  Styles.Render i have done Scripts.Render. Viewing the source helped me identify the problem